# Faster way to delete up to the 4th colon in a variable?semicolon

Tags: powershell, msmq

I'm trying to query MSMQ with Powershell, and then read (in my case) XML out of the BodyStream. Stripping out the crap before the XML is *slow*... like 200-500ms per record.

Pulling the XML out seems okay fast (below), but that replace takes forever.

```
$msmq = Get-MsmqQueue -Name "myqueuelovesme"
$var = Receive-MsmqQueue -input $msmq -Peek -Count 500 -Timeout 5000 -RetrieveBody | foreach {
$sr = $_.BodyStream.ToArray()
$pr = $enc.GetString($sr)
[xml]$clean= $pr -creplace ".*:Message:"
select-xml -xml $clean -XPath "/MyXML/Defin" | foreach {$_.node}
}
$var
```

The contents of bodystream look like this:

```
F:01.02.03:1234567890:Message:<MyXML><Defin xmlns:dsi="http:// [...]
```

The XML always starts after that 4th semicolon, so I don't think I can split/join (as the number of semicolons in the XML can change).  I see that creplace is faster than replace, but neither is great.

Any suggestions?  (And heck, is the rest of the code okay?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tonnes of options I imagine here. Not sure which would be the best one. I will try and add some as we go. For sure other solutions will show up. You said *you don't think you can split/join* well.... BLAM!

```
'F:01.02.03:1234567890:Message:<MyXML><Defin xmlns:dsi="http:// [...]'.Split(":",5)[-1]
```

Split the string by colons but only up to 5 elements. Then return only the last element which would be 
`<MyXML><Defin...`. You would apply this to your implementation as:

```
[xml]$clean= $pr.Split(":",5)[-1]
```

You could also just split on the first `<` using the same logic.

```
[xml]$clean= "<$($pr.Split("<",2)[-1])"
```

Since we are splitting on the `<` we just add it back to the string.

I did a `Measure-Command` test using an `indexOf` and `Split`. Running both 100000 times took about 2 seconds each. They were both neck and neck. Same test with `-creplace` took about 7 seconds. `Measure-Command` is not perfect and its results can be questioned but it would seem either answer here (so far) would perform better.

Comment: tested these. 50.  Old time, 17.323. First option, tried twice: .965 and .864.  Second option: .932 and .930.  THANKS TO BOTH OF YOU - giving Matt the vote because there's more explanation on what it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

How does this perform?

```
$clean = [xml]$pr.Substring($pr.IndexOf('<'))
```

Comment: @swonkie Testing this one first: old time, 18.24s. New time, 1.5s.  Holy crap!  THANKS!

Comment: Actually to the point where me using a stopwatch is stupid.  50 messages: old time, 17.323s. New time, .861s.  Each of the substrings one is taking under 3ms now.  Holy crap!  THANKS!